# Deploying custom setting using ant

Tags: deployment, migration-tool, customsetting

I was looking at this doc : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf

I am preparing a ant manifest for migration and cannot find custom setting in the doc, I usually stick to changeset and cannot find customsetting as a type.

Are customsettings stored as `<name><customobject></name>` ?

please clarify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you include your custom settings within the CustomObject type in your manifest.

For the various other types, the [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) has an excellent metadata reference for your org besides the many other tools that it has to offer.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question has been answered but just wanted to provide more help on using salesforce ANT script for deployment. To create package.xml, you can use ANT task 'packagegenerator'. This task pulls all the artifacts which have been modified/created since your last deployment. I created this task and it is open source. You can find it [here](https://github.com/msabiransari/salesforce-package-generator).

For more help you can take a look [here](https://medium.com/@msabiransari/salesforce-deployment-e79cc502a952).